# flutter webrtc remote stream

Tags: flutter, openvidu, flutter-webrtc

I am having a problem with onaddremotestream in flutter webrtc

I am following this guide  https://github.com/cyb3rcod3/flutter-openvidu-demo
trying to integrate flutter with openvidu https://docs.openvidu.io/en/2.24.0/tutorials/openvidu-hello-world/

openvidu web https://github.com/OpenVidu/openvidu-tutorials/tree/master/openvidu-hello-world

openvidu server working normally and when connecting web browser and iOS device the web browser sees both local and remote stream...but iOS device or emulator only sees local stream and no remote stream!

code used old android embeddings v1 so I had to update packages and add null safety for latest flutter webrtc

1. in signalling.dart

I replaced

```
 _localPeerConnection.addStream(_localStream);
```

with

```
_localStream?.getTracks().forEach((track) {print('adding our localtracks');_localPeerConnection?.addTrack(track,_localStream!);});
```

this made local stream show in screen

1. in signalling.dart

```
in functionFuture<RTCPeerConnection> _createRemotePeerConnection(RemoteParticipant remoteParticipant)
```

the below code for remote participant stream triggers

```
remotePeerConnection.onAddStream = (MediaStream stream) {
  print("should add remote  stream for remote participant");
  remoteParticipant.mediaStream = stream;
  if (this.onParticipantsStreamUpdate != null){
    this.onParticipantsStreamUpdate?.call(remoteParticipant);
  }
  if (this.onAddRemoteStream != null){
    print(' call onaddremotestream from remote participant');
    onAddRemoteStream?.call(stream);
  }
};
```

and in  UI  page  call_sample.dart

```
_signaling?.onAddRemoteStream = ((stream) {
  print('onAddRemoteStream: ${stream.id}');
  // stream.getVideoTracks()[0].addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(remoteRender));
  _remoteRenderer.srcObject = stream;


  // _remoteRenderer.srcObject = _signaling?.getRemoteStream();
  setState(() {});
});
```

gets triggered but the output of print is   **flutter: onAddRemoteStream: default**
and the screen is black/grey

I am not sure where the problem is since the browser sees the device means the openvidu is working and the problem is in flutter app!